# Created file access using USB in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'd like to know how can I access the photos that I saved with my Titanium Android app using the USB cable to copy for my PC.

I tried using the Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory and the Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory but both saved the file in the device (I could see using the ES File Explorer app) but when the device is connected to computer the same folder is not visible to copy.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory` will be only limited to your application, so you cannot access it outside the app. But by using `Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory` you can save the file to external storage and access it.

Also to make it visible to gallery you have to use [scanMediaFiles](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.Android).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello. But if I have another kind of files, like .txt or another extension?

Comment: are you checking in windows or linux?  Also what type of photos are in txt?? :/

Comment: I'm using Mac... But Windows happen the same. I have photos files (jpg) and some txt file with informations.